# MySQL: the aggregated outcome is incorrect but not sure why?

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to find out the customer with largest sales change from month to month (in this case, june to july).

Here's a mockup data I created for the sake of this practice:

```
mysql> select * from Sales1;
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| CustomerID | mydate     | purchase_amount |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
|         10 | 1996-08-02 |         2540.78 |
|         20 | 1999-01-30 |         1800.54 |
|         30 | 1995-07-14 |          460.33 |
|         10 | 1998-06-29 |            2400 |
|         50 | 1998-02-03 |          600.28 |
|         60 | 1998-03-02 |             720 |
|         10 | 1998-07-06 |             150 |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
mysql> select * from Sales2;
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| CustomerID | mydate     | purchase_amount |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
|         10 | 1996-06-02 |          540.78 |
|         20 | 1999-09-30 |          800.54 |
|         30 | 1995-07-14 |           60.33 |
|         40 | 1998-01-29 |             400 |
|         10 | 1998-07-03 |         2600.28 |
|         60 | 1998-03-02 |            1720 |
|         70 | 1998-05-04 |            4150 |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
```

According to above two tables, the answer should be the customer with **CustomerID 10** and with an **increase of sales 350.28 from June to July** in year 1998.

Below are my code to achieve the goal; basically I created two view, one consisting of sum of all **JUNE** sales for each customer for each year, and another one consisting of sum of all **JULY** sales for each customer for each year, and then subtract the **JUNE** sales from **JULY** sales:

```
CREATE VIEW sum6 AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, 
YEAR(mydate) AS year, 
MONTH(mydate) AS month,
SUM(purchase_amount) as amount
FROM Sales1
GROUP BY CustomerID, year, month
HAVING month = 6
) 
UNION ALL (
SELECT CustomerID,
YEAR(mydate) AS year, 
MONTH(mydate) AS month,
SUM(purchase_amount) as amount
FROM Sales2
GROUP BY CustomerID, year, month
HAVING month = 6) 
;

CREATE VIEW sum7 AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, 
YEAR(mydate) AS year, 
MONTH(mydate) AS month,
SUM(purchase_amount) as amount
FROM Sales1
GROUP BY CustomerID, year, month
HAVING month = 7
) 
UNION ALL (
SELECT CustomerID,
YEAR(mydate) AS year, 
MONTH(mydate) AS month,
SUM(purchase_amount) as amount
FROM Sales2
GROUP BY CustomerID, year, month
HAVING month = 7) 
;

SELECT CustomerID, year, (SUM(sum7.amount)-SUM(sum6.amount)) as diff
FROM sum6
JOIN sum7
USING(CustomerID, year)
GROUP BY CustomerID, year
;
```

However, my output is:

```
+------------+------+--------------------+
| CustomerID | year | diff               |
+------------+------+--------------------+
|         10 | 1998 | -2049.719970703125 |
+------------+------+--------------------+
```

While yes, the CustomerID and year values are correct, **the difference amount is not**.

I checked individually whether the sums for sum6 and sum7 are calculated correctly by CustomerID and year:

```
mysql> SELECT CustomerID, year, SUM(amount)
    -> FROM sum7
    -> GROUP BY CustomerID, year
    -> ;
+------------+------+-------------------+
| CustomerID | year | SUM(amount)       |
+------------+------+-------------------+
|         10 | 1998 | 2750.280029296875 |
|         30 | 1995 | 520.6599884033203 |
+------------+------+-------------------+
mysql> SELECT CustomerID, year, SUM(amount)
    -> FROM sum6
    -> GROUP BY CustomerID, year
    -> ;
+------------+------+------------------+
| CustomerID | year | SUM(amount)      |
+------------+------+------------------+
|         10 | 1996 | 540.780029296875 |
|         10 | 1998 |             2400 |
+------------+------+------------------+
```

And they are, and so I know that the GROUP BY is correct.

So then I tried to look at the individual sum amounts:

```
mysql> SELECT CustomerID, year, SUM(sum7.amount), SUM(sum6.amount)
    -> FROM sum6
    -> JOIN sum7
    -> USING(CustomerID, year)
    -> GROUP BY CustomerID, year
    -> ;
+------------+------+-------------------+------------------+
| CustomerID | year | SUM(sum7.amount)  | SUM(sum6.amount) |
+------------+------+-------------------+------------------+
|         10 | 1998 | 2750.280029296875 |             4800 |
+------------+------+-------------------+------------------+
```

So the SUM(sum7.amount) is correct BUT SUM(sum6.amount) is incorrect. But how come they can add up correctly when pulled individually, and only one of them is summed up incorrectly when combined? This inconsistency is driving me nuts...

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing `SELECT .. FROM (SELECT * FROM Sales1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Sales2) ... `? Also, you're using `HAVING` for conditions not related to the actual aggregate function. Is it still broken when using `WHERE month = n`?

Comment: Hi @Fritz thanks a lot for commenting! That is a very good point. I should have used that instead.... as for your 2nd point, yes it'll complain if i use WHERE instead of HAVING since the aggregation is indeed based on month value too.

Comment: `GROUP BY CustomerID, year(mydate), month(mydate) WHERE month(mydate) = 6` throws an error? `HAVING` only works like `WHERE` when there is no aggregate function. (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Fritz HAVING is used when there is aggregation correct? so ya when I change it to WHERE it throws an error. I just tried it now...

Answer (score 2):

### Your `JOIN` statements are incomplete.

You're joining `sum6` to `sum7` too loosely. To use your last case, your `JOIN` is duplicating records somehow. (2400 * 2 = 4800)

When you total them, you're somehow getting duplicate records from one of the views because of how your joins are set up. You need to check your [conditions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

To help narrow this down, Including all rows and not taking math operations until you can verify the data. Start with the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM sum6
JOIN sum7
USING(CustomerID, year)
```

and verify that only the rows you want to pair are pairing, and then go from there.

Comment: Hi Fritz, thanks a lot for your answer! I did specify the condition by using the statement "USING(CustomerID, year)" so I am joining them based on customerid and year. I see where you are going, but I'm not sure I understand how I can fix it... Any pointer would be helpful!

Comment: I've updated my answer. I believe that if you have your views appearing properly on their own, you should be able to `SELECT *` and view the pairings of the rows and determine what you need to tighten up.

Comment: no the code you provided has error b/c sum6 and sum7 have different months values. so cant join them? i actually tried do that too but i got the error "Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sum6.month' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to cut out the `GROUP BY`. That should work. The code is only joining on CID and year.

Comment: Hi Fritz!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! i took your advice from your previous comments on my question, and also the code you presented here helped me identify my root problem. THANK YOU SO MUCH AGAIN! I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to Fritz, I have came up with another solution that's simpler (at least to me).

Below are my codes to achieve my goals without problem:

```
CREATE VIEW all67 AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, YEAR(mydate) AS year,  MONTH(mydate) AS month, SUM(purchase_amount) AS amount
FROM Sales1
GROUP BY CustomerID, year, month
HAVING month = 6 OR month  = 7 
)
UNION ALL 
(
SELECT CustomerID, YEAR(mydate) AS year,  MONTH(mydate) AS month, SUM(purchase_amount) AS amount
FROM Sales2
GROUP BY CustomerID, year, month
HAVING month = 6 OR month  = 7 
)
;

SELECT CustomerID, year, july.amount - june.amount AS diff
FROM
(
SELECT CustomerID, year, month, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM all67
GROUP BY CustomerID, year, month
HAVING month = 6
) june
JOIN
(
SELECT CustomerID, year, month, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM all67
GROUP BY CustomerID, year, month
HAVING month = 7
) july
USING (CustomerID, year)
;
```

and now finally my answer came out all correct!!! 
Thanks Fritz a lot. and hopefully my answer is helping many of you out there with similar questions.

Cheers!